# C++ convert string to wstring and back with Minimal code

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, wstring

The following code converts a `string` to a `wstring` which I need to call the stemming method I am using. However, the `map` in which I am storing the stemmed words is full of `strings`. I looked around at some of the solutions on SO and many of the conversions from `wstring` to `string` are circa a dozen lines of code. **Is there any way to convert quickly (preferably inline or similar) from a `string` to a `wstring` and back?**

```
string ANSIWord("documentation");
wchar_t* UnicodeTextBuffer = new wchar_t[ANSIWord.length()+1];
wmemset(UnicodeTextBuffer, 0, ANSIWord.length()+1);
mbstowcs(UnicodeTextBuffer, ANSIWord.c_str(), ANSIWord.length());
wWord = UnicodeTextBuffer;
```

Otherwise, I will look into converting my `map` and other methods to use `wstring`.

**EDIT:**

Epiphany: I decided to place the entire conversion-method-conversion in a method of its own, thereby reducing it to the desired one line. However, I would still like to know out of curiousity/ for future reference.

Comment: Not really, if you want to do it right. You need to check for errors and compute the required output length in *some* fashion, after all.

Comment: See [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a function that includes the circa 12 lines of code that do the conversion, and then call that function?